# VB.NET End application in Form2

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Here's my scenario:

I have two forms named `Form1` and `Form2`.
`Form1` has a button.
When the button is pressed, `Form1` will become hidden and `Form2` will be shown.
If I close `Form2` by pressing `[x]` button on the top right of the form, the application is still running.
According what I get in my research, it seems I have to work with `FormClosingEventArgs`.
Anyone have any idea?

Comment: If Form1 is just hidden, the app is still running (assuming the code in "the button" is `Me.Hide`), so there is no way for the user to end the program. You could reshow Form1 when Form2 closes, or just dont do that.

Comment: You can write a little code that when form2 closes it also closes form1.

Comment: Subscribe the 2nd form's FormClosing event, make your form visible again.  Or just close it right away if you don't want it back at all.  If you do that then change the app's Shutdown Mode setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find Shutdown Mode in your application properties. There you will see two options.
1. When start up form closes.
2. When last form closes.

If you choose no.1 then until you close your start up form your application will not close but you can apply force close. eg.

```
    Private Sub Form2Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    End
End Sub
```

And if no.2 then your application will close automatically when last active form closes.

Hope this is ok

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not closing your first form. You are just hiding the first form instead of closing it. You should also close the first form. But, if you are creating an object of `Form2` in `Form1` then you can't close the first form. if you close it then the `Form2` will not be displayed because the object of `Form2` will be disposed initially. So, you should handle the `FormClosed` event of `Form2` in `Form1` when the `Form2` is being displayed.

```
'Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Dim form As New Form2
    AddHandler form.FormClosed, AddressOf Me.form2_FormClosed
    form.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub form2_FormClosed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.

```
Private Sub Form2Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Form1.Close()
End Sub
```

Please give more suggestion to me if there is another nice way :)

Comment: what i do if i have more hidden forms? each one is needed to close like this?